# Detect an error if the value is removed from the <option> tag

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I was trying my newly created script and found an issue. How to detect if the `value` attribute from the `<option>` tag is removed? I have the following script:

```
if (isset($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['day'])) {
  if ($_POST['day'] === 'pirmadienis') {
    echo 'Laugh on Monday, laugh for danger.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'antradienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Tuesday, kiss a stranger.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'treciadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Wednesday, laugh for a letter.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'ketvirtadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Thursday, something better.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'penktadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Friday, laugh for sorrow.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'sestadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Saturday, joy tomorrow.';
  }
} else {
  echo '<form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="day">Pasirinkite bet kurią dieną </label> 
        <select name="day">
          <option value="pirmadienis">Pirmadienis</option>
          <option value="antradienis">Antradienis</option>
          <option value="treciadienis">Trečiadienis</option>
          <option value="ketvirtadienis">Ketvirtadienis</option>
          <option value="penktadienis">Penktadienis</option>
          <option value="sestadienis">Šeštadienis</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Tęsti">
        </form>';
}

if (isset($_POST['day']) && empty($_POST['day'])) {
  echo 'Pasirinkite dieną!';
}
```

For example, we remove the `value` attribute using inspect element:

```
<option>Pirmadienis</option>
```

And submit the form. We don't get any errors, the form disappeared because of this if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['day'])) {
```

It's true, so `else` is not executed but the value of `$_POST['day']` array is also not found. So, how can detect that the user has deleted value attribute using `PHP`?

Comment: The test `if (isset($_POST['day']) && empty($_POST['day'])) {` should work.

Comment: Yes, it works if the value attribute is not removed but empty `value=""`. However, if we remove the value attribute `<option>Pirmadienis</option>`, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `value` attribute, it defaults to the text of the option. You should put an `else` clause at the end of the tests of all the possible values, and print an error there.

```
  if ($_POST['day'] === 'pirmadienis') {
    echo 'Laugh on Monday, laugh for danger.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'antradienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Tuesday, kiss a stranger.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'treciadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Wednesday, laugh for a letter.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'ketvirtadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Thursday, something better.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'penktadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Friday, laugh for sorrow.';
  } elseif ($_POST['day'] === 'sestadienis') {
      echo 'Laugh on Saturday, joy tomorrow.';
  } else {
      echo 'Pasirinkite dieną!';
  }
```